# Git retrieve a list of all files modified in a branch

Tags: linux, git, branch

How can I get a list of all the files that were changed in a branch? I can't do a git-diff because the branch is already merged into master.

I would need a way to list all the commits in a branch and extract the path of the files, without duplicates.

If anybody has done a thing like this before it will be really appreciated,

a lot of thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If we consider your branch as **BranchA** wich was branched from **master**, you can do:

```
git diff --name-status `git merge-base BranchA master`..BranchA
```

This will give you the list of changed files in branch prefixed with status (M for modified, A for added, D for deleted).

Answer (score 2):

This works if the branch is pointing to the merge commit:

```
git diff branch_name^..master --name-only
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git log` and figure out from which commit you want to know the differences. Let's say that you determine that the hash of the commit you want is `aaaaaa`. Then run:

```
git diff aaaaaa --stat
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same problem and @Michael Burtin's solution worked for the most part. However, I wanted to add this to a script that will work on any branch, so it cannot contain the branch name. This is what I came up with:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base master HEAD)
```

Which finds the closet ancestor of both master and the current branch, then diffs that commit with the current branch.